# displaying xml data with javascript, issue at end of function?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Trying to make a text/sample page for a future project.  I want to be able to list a certain amount of objects at a time from the xml document, with a button to load the next however many.  Sort of like a browsing catalog.  Here's what I got, and I'm pretty sure the problem is at the end of the listbythree function.  I just don't know how to plug that function into the specified div element on pageload.  any help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html />
<html>
<head>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  // code for IE6, IE5
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","books.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var i=0;
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book");
function listbythree()
{
    for (i;i<3;i++)
      {
      document.write("<div style='display:inline;float:left;background-color:#ffff99;padding:10px;width:300px;height:210px;margin:5px;font-size:14px;'><img style='float:left;padding-right:4px' src=");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("cover")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " />");
      document.write("<em>" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</em><br/>");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br/>");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("pub")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br/>");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("edition")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br/>");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("genre")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br/>");
      document.write("Have I Read: " + x[i].getElementsByTagName("read")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</div>");
      }
    document.getElementById("booksbythree").innerHTML=this;
};


function next()
    {
    if (i<x.length-1)
  {
  i+3;
  listbythree();
  }
}

function previous()
{
if (i>0)
  {
  i-3;
  listbythree();
  }
}

</script>

</head>
<body onload="listbythree()">

<div id="booksbythree"></div><br/><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="previous()" value="<<" />
<input type="button" onclick="next()" value=">>" />

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop only loops when `i<3`, so it will never show any elements further than the third. You can do the following to fix this. Also your next button is adding 3 to `i` when your for loop is also adding to `i`, this would make you skip 3 elements each time you click next.

```
function listbythree()
{
    var j = i+3;
    for (i;i<j&&i<x.length;i++)
    {
    ....
    }
}

function next()
{
if (i<x.length-1)
{
   listbythree();
}
}
```

On a second note I would suggest that you use jQuery, it can make the AJAX and XML parsing much easier.

Comment: Yeah I get that I'll have to edit that part later, but for now the function is loading on page load, but the buttons for next and previous, which should show up below the three entries, are not showing up.  The list by three function should get called to the div element at the bottom, and below it, the next and previous buttons.  Right now its just loading the function and nothing else.

Comment: Just tried your suggestions, and even with them the next and previous buttons aren't showing up